# How to check if the start of a string has specific character using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where I have to check whether a word has `+` followed by space as the first two characters using regex.I tried creating regex and used match method, but the method always returns null.Could anyone suggest me how to create regex for the following condition?

```js
getWord: function() {
    var index = this.getIndexOfSelectedText(),

      words = this.state.editorText.slice(0, index.start),

      var selectedWords = words.split('\n').pop();
    console.log('selectedWords', selectedWords);
    var exp = '/^\+\s/'
    console.log(selectedWords.match(exp));
    if (selectedWords.match(exp)) {
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: `I tried creating regex and used match method` - show what you've tried - that way we get a better understanding of your requirements as well

Comment: Why not using `if(exp.test(selectedWords))`

Comment: `/^\+\s/.test(selectedWords)`

Comment: The regexp you're using does not work? How does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try regular expression `^\+\s+`... Please follow test [here](https://regex101.com/r/F4evSB/1)